# How to refresh previous screen/page list when come back from a page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two pages one is list view and another is form kind of page. Using sqflite with streambuilder for crud operation, Once i enter input and save from second screen list view from screen one should be updated.

**First Screen:**

List view will be return from sqflite datatbase like this.

```
    Widget getDebtorsWidget() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: debtorBloc.debtors,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Debtor>> snapshot) {
        return getDebtorCardWidget(snapshot);
      },
    );
  }

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                tooltip: 'Add an entry',
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => DebtorFormFullScreenDialog(),
                        fullscreenDialog: true,
                      ));
                      //_showAddDebtorSheet(context);
                },
              ),

     void _showAddDebtorSheet(BuildContext context) {
    ......
    }
```

**Second screen:**

```
onPressed: () {
                    final newDebtor =
                        Debtor(name: _debtorNameFormController.value.text);
                    if (newDebtor.name.isNotEmpty) {

                      debtorBloc.addDebtor(newDebtor);

                      //dismisses the bottomsheet
                      Navigator.pop(context, false);
                    }
                  },
```

_showAddDebtorSheet() is on same screen when enter data with in this listview updates immediately. But when when do it on second screen is not listview not updates even when i navigate back to first screen.

Note: Pls notify me if you need extra information.

Answer (score 6):

You can `await` for [`Navigator.of(context).push`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) (which could also [receive return value](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) from second page `Navigator.of(context).pop(value)`) and then `setState(() {});` in first page context to make it refresh.

In your example it would look like:

```
            onPressed: () async {
                await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => DebtorFormFullScreenDialog(),
                    fullscreenDialog: true,
                  )
                );
                setState(() {});
            },
```

Comment: sorry but u and i same time upload answere